# Metatags not generated for views pages

Tags: 7, views, meta-tags

I have installed the metatag module but it only works on the node pages and does not generate tags for the views pages.

I have also tried the metatags_quick module which provide the metatags per path but it also did not generate tags on the views pages.

Any other module which will be useful for views pages or any other method?

Comment: According to this thread (http://drupal.org/node/1804356) over on D.O. the latest beta from April 14th of Metatags supports meta tags on views...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use metatags_quick for our websites with no problem. You must make sure you've **checked** the tickbox "Use path-based meta tags" in `admin/config/search/metatags_quick` under the fieldset `GLOBAL SETTINGS` (it might be collapsed by default)

Comment: it was my mistake. checked the path based meta tags checkboxes but instead of clicking the attach button I was clicking the submit button. thanks for the answer.

Comment: are the managed paths exportable via features because I don't see anything in the features for the metatags quick managed paths?

Comment: Not sure, we always put meta description on the live database, as it's considered a content. Never really had the necessity to export the actual metadata, however you can export the "Use path based meta tags" setting via strongarm+feature